# Triangle , C++ construction, problem with calculating angles

Tags: c++, triangle-count

I have a problem with my homework.

1) I should write the function SSS with inputs a, b and c. I need to output alpha, beta and gamma.

2) I should write the function SWS with inputs a, b, and gamma. And I need to output c, alpha and beta.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

double SSS_alpha(double a, double b, double c){

    int bot1 = -2*b*c;
    if(bot1==0.0){
        return 0.0;
    }

    double alpha = acos((a*a-b*b-c*c)/bot1);
    const double rad = 0.5729577951308232088;
    return alpha*rad;

}

double SSS_beta(double a, double b, double c){

    double bot2 = -2*c*a;
    if(bot2==0.0){
        return 0.0;
    }

    double beta = acos((b*b-c*c-a*a)/bot2);
    const double rad = 0.5729577951308232088;
    return beta*rad;
}

double SSS_gamma(double a, double b, double c){

    double bot3 = -2*b*a;
    if(bot3==0.0){
        return 0.0;
    }

    double gamma = acos((c*c-a*a-b*b)/bot3);
    const double rad = 0.5729577951308232088;
    return gamma*rad;
}


double WSW_seite_c(double a, double b, double gamma){
    double c_1 = (a*a+b*b-2*a*b*cos(gamma));
    double c = sqrt(c_1);
    return c;

}



int main(){
    cout << SSS_alpha(5.0, 7.0, 8.0)<<endl;
    cout <<SSS_beta(5.0, 7.0, 8.0)<<endl;
    cout <<SSS_gamma(5,7,8)<<endl;
    cout <<"Seite c: "<<WSW_seite_c(5, 7, 0.81)<<endl;

}
```

I can only return one argument in one function. And I have a lot of functions for task 1:for alpha, for beta, for gamma. And I don't know how I can write it in one function. I wrote only one function for finding c for task 2.

I am new to C++. I would be happy if you can help me.:)

Comment: You can group in a `struct` some values. Then pass a reference to that `struct`. Inside the function you can change those struct-values.

Comment: @Ripi2 This is a good idea, but why not just return the struct (as a return value) from the function?

Comment: @Rulle. Your idea is also valid, for example when you don't want to change the original struct.

Comment: Please quote your assignment verbatim. "Output'  could mean that your function should print these results rather than return them.

Answer (score 2):

First you dont need `cstdio` if you include `iostream` which you should preferably do in C++ since `cstdio` is just the C library migrated to C++.

As for your problem it sounds like you need to pass the variables by value. Your favourite C++ Book should tell you that there are cases like yours, where you need to "return" more than one value. In that case you can pass pointers(C-Style) or the safer references to functions which kind of act like pointers.

So you actually would define your function as follows:

```
void SSS(double a, double b, double c, double & alpha, double & beta, double & gamma);
```

Or as stated by @Ripi2 pack the values in a `struct` and return a value of that type :

```
/* Thanks to NathanOliver in the comments */
struct Values {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

Values SSS(double a, double b, double c) {
    Values values;
    /* Do stuff */
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Output parameters are an anti-pattern.  They force you to declare the return value before you call the function and you can miss very handy optimizations like RVO and NRVO.  If you need to return multiple objects you should return by struct/class/pair/tuple

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree with this. I believe the use of output parameters is (false?) belief that you are going to avoid an extra copy operation by avoiding copy the result to the stack or something like that. But compiler are usually smart enough to optimize that away... at least for simple values.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean by "They force you to declare the return value before you call the function[...]"? Because the variables have fixed types when declaring the function?

Comment: To call `void SSS(double a, double b, double c, Values & values);` I have to do `Values values; SSS(a, b, c, values);` (had to declare an uninitialized object in order to pass it to the fucntion) instead of being able to do `Values values = SSS(a, b, c);`

Comment: also, a `struct` is not an array

Answer (score 2):

Returning a struct or using a class Triangle as proposed are perfect solutions and it is what I generally use.

However, in some simple cases, returning more than one value through a tuple can be quite convenient.
I showed a simple "working" example below.
Note that I will generally avoid this kind of solution for more than 3 return objects, to avoid confusion.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <tuple>
std::tuple<double, double, double> f(double x, double y){
    double a = x;
    double b = x+y;
    double c = x-y;
    return std::make_tuple(a, b, c);
}
int main() {
    double a, b, c;
    std::tie (a, b, c) = f (1.0, 2.0);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << "\n";
    std::cout << "b = " << b << "\n";
    std::cout << "c = " << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I hope the code is self explaining.
The syntax can be simplified with C++17. I did not use these simplifications because my current compiler is not compatible!
This approach can be combined with the struct one, as one can return several structs through a tuple.

Edit: I just see that NathanOliver already mentioned the tuple possibility in a comment...

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` will be the simplest way of doing what you want. You can also create a class, but it might be an overkill solution for a homework (they basically are the same, but see my comment thread to get my point of view on that matter).

a struct declaration goes like this :

```
struct containerName
{
    int val_a;
    double val_b;
    //and so on : you put what ever you need
}
```

The struct then basically becomes a type you can use pretty much like `int`, `double`, `bool` etc.

[Here's a nice reading](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/) on `struct` and how to use it

Comment: A `struct` is a `class`, they just have different default access specifies.  Any place you can use `struct` you can use `class` as well.

Comment: in c++, a class is a struct, not the other way around. Structs were usable in C before classes were implemented in C++

Comment: @Sirmyself Not in a C-Struct sense. In C, structs can only contain data members and dont have any access specifiers. In C++ there came classes and C++ structs are the same as C++ classes.

Comment: @Sirmyself They are the same thing.  Both can have constructors, both can have member functions, both can be polymorphic.  There is no difference, except the default access specifier.

Comment: anyways, it's basically true and might get too philosophical to be relevant for this answer. To me a class has function declarations while structs don't. (I know we can have functions in a struct, but I personally prefer to see it that way)

Comment: What do you mean *both don't have the same way of implementing the ability to have a function*?  A member function in a class is implemented the exact same way it is in a `struct`

Comment: what I said was true for C, but not in C++, my bad

Comment: Ok, thanks, couldn't I do it without struct and classes, because we didn't have classes and structs yet?

Comment: @kg-boys without structs or classes, yes, see Yastanub's answer, but it is an anti-pattern and is frowned upon in most cases.

Comment: @kg-boys anyways, if your teacher wants to prevent you from going further in your learning, tell him to come see me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can only return one object from a function. But you can have it return a compound object, like a struct or a class. Traditionally you use structs for data only objects, because that is what they were in C.

```
struct Triangle
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};
```

Then you can return a `Triangle` object from a function. And access its members this way:

```
Triangle tri1;     // first, create an instance of the struct
tri1.a = 5.0f;      // assign a value to a member
```

It's good practice to choose meaningful names for your data types (just like with your variables) and always design the data types so that they represent what they are named.

---

To make the code more expressive you could take it further with a more object oriented approach. You could give the data type `Triangle` member functions which calculate its angles, so that you can "ask" the `Triangle` what its angles are.

(You should also name it a class at that point because it it is not a pure data structure anymore, but that is a matter of convention. in C++ structs and classes are almost the same.)

```
class Triangle
{
    public:
    // everything in this section can be accessed from outside

    // this is a constructor. It is a special function that lets you create a Triangle
    Triangle(double pa, double pb, double pc)
        : a(pa), b(pb), c(pc)   // initialize the members
    {}

    // getters for the private members (not needed but that way they can't directly be changed)
    double get_a() const
    {
        return a;
    }
    double get_b() const
    {
        return b;
    }
    double get_c() const
    {
        return c;
    }

    double alpha() const;
    double beta() const;
    double gamma() const;
    // should be const because they dont change anything about the object

    private:   
    // the default access for classes, everything in this section can only be accessed by member functions

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
};

// member function definitions outside of class declaration
double Triangle::alpha() const
{
    // calculate and return alpha...
}
double Triangle::beta() const
{
    // calculate and return beta...
}
double Triangle::gamma() const
{
    // ...
}
```

You can use this class this way:

```
int main()
{
    // create a Triangle by calling the constructor
    Triangle tri1(5.0, 7.0, 8.0);
    std::cout << "Alpha: " << tri1.alpha() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Beta: " << tri1.beta() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Gamma: " << tri1.gamma() << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: The constructor is basically the function that is used to initialize all the members of a class with a value. what probably confuses you is the initializer list, which is this part `: a(pa), b(pb), c(pc)`. That is special for constructors and basically just puts values into the members directly. The constructor also has a body ( the `{}` curly brakets) which is just like any other function body.

Comment: For your second task I would write a stand-alone function which just takes the sides a and b and the angle gamma as inputs and returns a Triangle with all the sides initialized. 
You could also write that function as a constructor for Triangle, but that would require you to first introduce types for "TriangleSide" and "Angle", because if you call a constructor with 3 doubles (a, b and gamma) the compiler will not know if you want to call the constructor taking 3 sides or the one taking 2 sides and an angle.

Comment: thanks, I took 2 sides and an angle gamma. And I think it worked fine

Comment: tri1 is the name of the Triangle object. `Triangle name;` creates an object of type `Triangle` named `name`, which is _uninitialized_, just as with other types as `int` or `double`. When you want to initialize it, you have to call the constructor: `Triangle name(5.0, 7.0, 8.0);` (`Triangle name = Triangle(5.0, 7.0, 8.0);` is the same thing).